# Finding Measurements before Designing Vehicle Stickers or Decals?

Tags: print-production

I'm to design decals that include logos and company information when I've only available clue is the Car Models (2013 Toyota Tundra and 2007 Ford e150 Cargo Van) for which the designs are intended. The problem is that I can't find that out how to measure the actual artwork on the printed surface hence the car body parts.

I'm not a professional designer but I'd like to know if I were a pro designer what necessary steps I would have taken before attempting the design on either Photoshop or Illustrator? I mean how should a designer know the actual sizing or measurements of the resulting artwork when the only info delivered is a vehicle name and its model?

Comment: There are templates available and most places that specifically print car wraps and decals will have these templates so you should ask them first..

Comment: ..otherwise search for vehicle wrap templates. There are plenty of places that sell packs with hundreds of templates but they aren't cheap. I was in a similar situation a while back and I did find the template I needed without having to pay for it but it did take me days to find!

Comment: At last, I've got some ideas from your comments. Appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three routes some typically use.

If you plan to use Photoshop one of the top vehicle templates over the years has been thebadwrap.com.  Ive used these in past and it comes with a pretty close psd file and a file with measurements.

If you use Illustrator I would suggest getting provehicleoutlines.com. Their outlines and measurements are usually within inches.

Both solutions will cost you several hundred dollars so consider it an investment.  I do believe provehicles sells individual but you'd have to try their site.  If you do not want to spend several hundred you could look for 3D vehicle renderings since some modelers do base the work on actual dimensions.  Just ask before you buy if it was measured.

Even though I do suggest all of this you still can't beat going to a car dealership with a tripod, camera and tape measure and taking a good picture and then measuring where it should go.  We took actual pictures of the clients vehicle and measurements so they would get the general idea of what their branding would look like.  I would take a picture perpendicular to the vehicle and make sure I get the area I need.  Use the software to make a scale of the area pictured and place my design where it should go.